# Artifactory - Problems with overit-central and This item is not cached

Tags: caching, artifactory

We've been experiencing problems with our overit-central repository on Artifactory. Some elements appear as "not-cached" and while trying to retrieve them from a build, we're encountering an "element not found" error. That same element does exist in the overit-central repo, but somehow our Artifactory instance doesn't seem to find it or cache it. (The problem doesn't happen with all the elements of the repo, and we don't know why. Some of them are actually cached)

We've already run a re-index of said repository but still the "This item is not cached" continues to appear.
We tried creating a new remote repository hooked to the same url and running some maven re-indexes from Artifactory, but it didn't help.

How do we force the caching of the elements from Artifactory? The documentation in the JFrog support page mentions it, but doesn't explain how to do it.

Thank you in advance
Regards

Answer (score 0):

A remote repository in Artifactory is a mirror of the endpoint you have configured. It doesn't download the artifacts by default and this is the reason it says "Artifact is not cached". It is the intended behavior and it lets you know that you have never downloaded this artifact.

In order to cache an artifact, you have to simply download it from the remote endpoint. This can be done in two ways:

1. From the UI - Right click --> download
2. Using the API "curl -uUSERNAME:PASSWORD http://ARTIFACTORY_URL:PORT/artifactory/REMOTE_REPOSITORY/PATH_TO_ARTIFACT

Once the artifact is downloaded, it means that it is cached and you will be able to see it in the "name-of-the-remote-repository-**cache**" repository which shows the downloaded cached artifacts.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
Regarding the "From the UI - Right click --> download", when I right-click on the artifact, the menu that appears only says: "native browser" or "refresh".

Where exactly am I supposed to find this "download" option?

Comment: When you right click on the desired artifact it should give the option to download. Also there should be an option in the top right of the page (all marked in the provided screenshot here - https://imgur.com/a/0xCuHWa)